# Pass output from first command as input to second command such that the first command runs in current shell

Tags: shell, posix

The following code describes my issue.

```
# File: foo.sh

# We have a work function that may define variables and produce some
# complex output.
work()
{
    a=foo
    ps -ef
}

# This function uses the work function.
f()
{
    # We want to filter the complex output produced by work function but
    # at the same time we want that any variables defined by work
    # function is available in this function.
    work | head -n 2

    # Since pipeline launches subshells, the variable defined by work
    # function is no longer available in this function.
    echo a: $a
}

f
```

Here is the output.

```
$ sh foo.sh
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 Jul15 ?        00:00:03 /sbin/init
a:
```

Since the pipe creates a subshell which means the variables defined in `work()` are lost when we returned to `f()`, I fixed the problem in this manner.

```
# File: bar.sh 

# We have a work function that may define variables and produce some
# complex output.
work()
{
    a=foo
    ps -ef
}

# This function uses the work function.
f()
{
    # We want to filter the complex output produced by work function but
    # at the same time we want that any variables defined by work
    # function is available in this function.
    work > out.txt
    head -n 2 out.txt
    echo a: $a
}

f
```

Here is the output.

```
$ sh bar.sh 
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 Jul15 ?        00:00:03 /sbin/init
a: foo
```

Although the second script works fine for this toy example, it can lead to problems (solveable problems though) when `f()` ends up calling itself in a recursion which would lead to `out.txt` being overwritten by the called-f() when the caller-f() would still be relying on it. Of course, it can be solved by taking sufficient care about the usage of `out.txt`, i.e. use `out.txt` only before f() calls itself and avoid using `out.txt` below the call.

This made me wonder if there is any way to solve this problem without relying on a temporary file being created. Is there a way to pass the output from `work` to another command without having to resort to file I/O such that `work` executes in the current shell? I am looking for solutions that can run on any POSIX shell.

Comment: There's a **terrible**, but simple [and portable] way to do it if executing `work` twice isn't a problem for you (and assuming the second call of `work` behaves and outputs exactly the same as the first call): `work >& /dev/null && work | head -n 2`

Comment: POSIX shell functions use *global* variables by default, so this `unset bar ; foo() {  bar=baz ; } ; oof() { foo ; echo $bar ; } ; oof`, returns: `baz`.  To change the default, use `local`, like this: `unset bar ; foo() { local bar=baz ; } ; oof() { foo ; echo $bar ; } ; oof`, which returns nothing.   Given that, it looks as if this Q has got shell *functions* confused with shell *scripts*.  Shell scripts usually run in a subshell, and cannot change their parental environment.

Comment: @agc I don't understand how your comment is relevant to my question. How is `local` even relevant here? I don't want to lose the variable definitions. I want the variable definitions to *remain intact*. Also, `local` is not guaranteed to be available in a POSIX compliant shell. The `local` keyword is not specified by POSIX. For example, `yash` does not support the `local` keyword. I believe you have completely misunderstood my question.

Comment: @agc No, I am not confused about shell functions and shell scripts here. In this question, what I am concerned about is that *pipelines* *may* run in subshells and therefore any variables defined in a pipeline may be lost once the pipeline terminates. I don't want the variable definitions to be lost. Did you read that part of the question?

Comment: Hmm.  I was not aware of `local` being un*POSIX*, my default assumption being "*if `dash` has it, it must be POSIX*".  Please specify exactly which *shell* (and version of it) the above code was run on, along with any relevant shell invocation options (i.e. options which ensure *POSIX* compliance).

Comment: Re "did I read that part of the question"?  Not well enough apparently.  One problem that stands out on re-perusal is that the question as presented is not *minimal*.  There's little need for such long and involved comments.  Using  `ps` output is a needless complication.  Maybe the present maximal presentation is obscuring the question.

Comment: Going with your own solution; Instead of writing to a file with a static name, use `mktemp` or an equivalent utility to create a unique filename to write to.

Comment: This is more minimal, and paste-able:  in `yash` v2.39 (Ubuntu) run: `work() { a=foo ; } ; unset a ; f() { work | cat > /dev/null ;  echo a: $a ; } ; f`, then compare it to:  `work() { a=foo ; } ; unset a ; f() { work       > /dev/null ;  echo a: $a ; } ; f`.  Only the one without the pipe prints "foo".

Answer (score 2):

A kludge, (tested in `yash`), to output the variable to *file descriptor 3* and bypass `head`, then copy it back to *STDIN*:

```
{ { work ; echo a: $a 1>&3 ; } | head -n 2 ; } 3>&1
```

Output:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 Jul15 ?        00:00:41 /sbin/init splash
a: foo
```

Note two levels of curly braces:

1. Just before the end, to move *file descriptor 3* back to *STDIN* without `head` seeing it.
2. To keep `work` and `echo` in the same shell.

---

The same code as above, in a function `f`:

```
f() { { { work ; echo a: $a 1>&3 ; } | head -n 2 ; } 3>&1 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a function `pseudopipe` for executing pipes in the requested manner (i.e. the first command of the pipe is executed in the current shell). Note, however, that the implementation creates temporary files and thus doesn't meet the requirement of avoiding file I/O.

**Usage:**

Any of the following forms and other variations will work:

```
pseudopipe "cmd1|cmd2"
pseudopipe 'cmd1|cmd2'
pseudopipe cmd1\|cmd2
```

**Limitations of the current implementation:**

- Only pipes made of two commands are handled correctly
- The commands must not contain a quoted or escaped '`|`' character. For example, the following will not work as expected:

  ```
  pseudopipe "work|grep '|'"
  ```
- Your script must not use the reserved variables **`PSEUDOPIPE_TMPDIR`**, **`PSEUDOPIPE_CMD1`**, and **`PSEUDOPIPE_CMD2`**

**Implementation and example:**

```
#!/bin/sh

pseudopipe()
{
    PSEUDOPIPE_TMPDIR=$(mktemp -d)
    PSEUDOPIPE_CMD1=$(echo "$@"|sed 's/|/\n/g'|head -n 1)
    PSEUDOPIPE_CMD2=$(echo "$@"|sed 's/|/\n/g'|tail -n 1)
    mkfifo "$PSEUDOPIPE_TMPDIR"/fifo
    eval "$PSEUDOPIPE_CMD2 < $PSEUDOPIPE_TMPDIR/fifo &" \
         "$PSEUDOPIPE_CMD1 > $PSEUDOPIPE_TMPDIR/fifo ;" \
         "rm -r $PSEUDOPIPE_TMPDIR"
    wait $!
}

work()
{
    a=foo
    ps -ef
}

f()
{
    a=bar
    echo "before pseudopipe: a: $a"
    pseudopipe "work|head -n 2"
    echo "after pseudopipe:  a: $a"
}

f
```

**Output:**

```
$ sh pseudopipe.sh 
before pseudopipe: a: bar
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 Jul22 ?        00:00:06 /sbin/init splash
after pseudopipe:  a: foo
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you want multiple pieces of information from the subshell.  One solution is to put everything you want from the subshell into the standard output pipe and process it all back on the parent shell side:

```
work()
{
    a=foo
    echo $a
    ps -ef
}
```

Then you have some parsing work to do on the parent shell side.  Here I set the separator to a newline and convert the return string to an array with one line at each array index:

```
f()
{
    output=$(work | head -n 3)
    IFS=$'\n'
    lines=($output)
    a=${lines[0]}
    echo ${lines[1]}
    echo ${lines[2]}
    echo a=$a
}

f
```

Another solution is to use named pipes and to assign each variable you are interested in into its own named pipe.  On the subshell side you create and write the pipes:

```
mkfifo /tmp/variable_a
echo $a > /tmp/variable_a
```

On the parent shell side you read from the same named pipe:

```
read a < /tmp/variable_a
rm -f /tmp/variable_a
```